# Bitemporal solutions for Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Do you recommend any pattern/strategy or product that can help with the development of a bitemporal database for Microsoft SQL 2008?

[About bitemporal](http://www.timeconsult.com/TemporalData/TemporalDB.html)

Comment: Saw this book (http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Bitemporal-Data-3826742) being pimped in this linked in group (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Managing-Time-Relational-Databases-Temporal/dp/0123750415) but it looks like a good one :)

Answer (score 2):

This might help: [A Primer on Managing Data Bitemporally](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/a-primer-on-managing-data-bitemporally/)

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution per se - but interesting articles on the topic:

- [Temporal Datatypes in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-datatypes-in-sql-server/) (by Joe Celko)
- [Database Design: A Point in Time Architecture](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll read them and perhaps find something that can help everyone out..

Answer (score 1):

The book "Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL" and other papers are available here http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html#books

Author Richard T. Snodgrass is professor of Computer Science at the University of Arizona.
I'm currently reading this excellent book: it deals with bitemporal tables in the first chapters.

Answer (score 1):

I see this company has a bi-temporal Framework developed for SQL Server. They call it the Asserted Versioning Framework - AVF.  They have a video that shows how it is integrated into normal T_SQL.  Looks cool.

http://www.assertedversioning.com/